# Extract property type from a oneof

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got a type a such:

```js
type OneOf =
  | {
      $case: 'one';
      one: One;
    }
  | {
      $case: 'two';
      two: Two;
    }
  | {
      $case: 'three';
      three: Three;
    };
```

I want to create a new type to be able to get from the input `OneOf`, get the output `One | Two | Three`.

I have tried many different things, including one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2398593) with `UnionToIntersection` in the hope that with an intersection, I could simply exclude the `$case`, loop on the keys and return the type.

I always get a `never` type as output though.

Essentially, I thought I could get away with it with the following:

```js
type ExtractOneOfTypes<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [key in K]: T extends { $case: key } ? T[key] : never;
}[K];
```

Because in my oneOf, for each `$case`, on that same object there is a property name that is the same as the `$case` value. But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `Omit<…, '$case'>` not that conditional type to omit the `$case`

Comment: Just tried, it gives `{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You you can `infer` the literal value type of `$case` and then check if it's a `keyof T` using a nested [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like so:

```
type One = { one: string };
type Two = { two: number };
type Three = { three: boolean };

type OneOf =
  | { $case: "one"; one: One }
  | { $case: "two"; two: Two }
  | { $case: "three"; three: Three };

type ExtractOneOfTypes<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends { [Key in K]: infer U }
  ? U extends keyof T
    ? T[U]
    : never
  : never;

type ExtractedType = ExtractOneOfTypes<OneOf, "$case">;
//    ^? type ExtractedType = One | Two | Three
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdtAvFA3lA9ggXFAzsAJwEs4BzKAXwG4AoUSKAFQHd0pk1hWc4BXAWwBGEApVr1ojABYEISVFGAy5OQenQAbCAEM4YmnXDR4EGADN2NKFAA%20CgCQBjbbgg4ARJgjuqGbLARKK1sHZ1cPLnQfRW4mViDrOzQnFzcodyVZb19MlSZlaGoDCSgAUQAPQm1HYBNzRiNcAB5GABooAGkoCEqIOAATXCgAawgQdAtGAD52Jm7egaG0AG0OsagSToBdHBIzESgAVQSoAH4j%20eA%20wZGxiaZg63PGZcOtx6geCAA3EWCv34EWiGBgVKo1CD9BoMZBggjVWoIeqNJp1MztdwpVzuKa0AD0eOs1gAeqcaEA)

Comment: This is a amazing. Man I've been banging my head on this one. I tried something around those lines (a bit simpler) bit it didn't work at all. Just couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks a lot!